# exporting and importing .sql in pgAdmin 4

Tags: pgadmin-4, postgresql-10

I'm trying to import a table using pgAdmin 4

I backed up the tables by right click on table, then in menu click on backup, then in Format choice Plain and save file as postgresql_food_table.sql

The back up process ran successfully

I removed the table

I tried to import it back by using Query Tool in Tool tab.
When I tried to execute it, it gives me this error :

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Anyone knows what I did wrong?